# How to create a while loop that adds user input(which is an int) into a list and stops when user hits enter?

Tags: python, list, input

This is the sample output I should get:

```
Enter data point (as an integer): 87
Enter data point (as an integer): 85
Enter data point (as an integer): 74
Enter data point (as an integer): 81
Enter data point (as an integer): 82
Enter data point (as an integer): 78
Enter data point (as an integer): 79
Enter data point (as an integer): 82
Enter data point (as an integer): 85
Enter data point (as an integer): 79
Enter data point (as an integer): 76
Enter data point (as an integer): 72
Enter data point (as an integer): 70
Enter data point (as an integer): 
Data list:  [87, 85, 74, 81, 82, 78, 79, 82, 85, 79, 76, 72, 70]
Min of data list: 70
Max of data list: 87
Sorted data list:  [70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 79, 79, 81, 82, 82, 85, 85, 87]
```

Comment: I am not sure that this should be closed and the question which was previously answered allowed for a string of numbers separated by commas, whereas this question specifically asks for hitting `enter` after each input.

Answer (score 0):

iter has a nice trick in that you can pass a sentinel value that will signal that it is done, and it will stop when encountered

```
print("Enter points ... empty to stop")
result = list(iter(input, ""))
print(result)
```